# Back-end Python para o Front-end

Tags: python

Fiz uma aplicação simples que cadastra uns dados num banco sqlite3, toda essa parte do Back-end ta feita em Python com arquivos.py rodando no terminal mesmo, para o meu uso já me serve excelentemente.
Agora quero visualizar os dados em uma pagina web até pra estudar HTML CCS e JS. Tem como consultar os dados do Sqlite3 em JavaScript? para preencher os dados na pagina web, mesmo que tenha um arquivo.py servindo esses dados, qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Criando um servidor web que utilize os scripts ou acesse o sqlite3 e forneça os dados pro JS via requisições HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tem como consultar os dados do Sqlite3 em JavaScript?

Na verdade **sim**.... O sqlite foi compilado para javascript e é chamado `sql.js`. Pode ser baixado aqui https://github.com/kripken/sql.js

Pequeno exemplo de uso:

```
var sql = window.SQL
var db = new sql.Database(banco);
var res = db.exec("SELECT * FROM hello");
console.log(res);
```

Aqui tem um exemplo mais completo http://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/

---

> mesmo que tenha um arquivo.py servindo esses dados, qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Apesar de ser possível como mostrei acima, é **bastante incomum** usar javascript para ler sqlite. O mais usual é criar uma aplicação cliente/servidor - o cliente é o navegador e acessa um endereço de rede, onde o servidor, escrito em python, está rodando e servindo solicitações. Para usar esse método você deve escolher um *framework* web, ou seja, uma biblioteca de funções para facilitar a criação de um serviço web. Existem muitos: `django`, `sanic`, `flask`, `cherrypy`... Cada um com suas vantagens e desvantagens, uns mais completos, outros mais flexíveis...

Pra finalizar deixo um exemplo super simples usando `flask` e `sqlalchemy`; O objetivo do exemplo é mostrar algo funcionando, logo, você pode salvá-lo em um script `teste_web.py` e rodá-lo, vai funcionar diretamente.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from flask import Flask, request

e = create_engine('sqlite:///arquivo.db', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=e)
Base = declarative_base(bind=e)
class Usuario(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'usuarios'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nome = Column(String(200))
Base.metadata.create_all()

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def indice():
    s = Session()
    result = '<html>' # monta variavel com html a retornar
    if request.method == "POST":
        usuario = Usuario(nome=request.form["nome"])
        s.add(usuario)
        s.commit()
        result += '<p>Usuario incluido com sucesso!</p>'
    result += '<table><tr><th>ID</td><th>Nome</th></tr>' #cabecalho
    for usuario in s.query(Usuario):
        result += '<tr><td>{0.id}</td><td>{0.nome}</td></tr>'.format(usuario)
    result += '</table><form method="POST">Incluir novo usuario:'
    result += '<input name="nome" /><input type="submit"></form><html>'
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Este exemplo simplificado irá criar o banco de dados em sqlite com uma tabela chamada `usuarios` e em seguida estará aguardando seu acesso no endereço `http://localhost:5000`. Ao acessar este endereço com o seu navegador, poderá ver o conteúdo da tabela e incluir novos usuários:

[image: web]

Lembre-se que este é apenas um simples exemplo - Na hora de desenvolver sua aplicação, é preciso levar mais do que isso em consideração; Um dos pontos a mudar é que estamos criando HTML manualmente, o correto seria usar uma linguagem de template para facilitar a geração de html (como por exemplo `jinja2`);

Espero ter ajudado e te dado um empurrão na direção certa.